# How to perform query string search on term containing hyphens in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I know this issue has been discussed in several other posts, but my case is a little bit different since I have the following constraints:

- I cannot change the mapping of the fields
- I cannot perform any action that will result in reindexing or creating a new index.

So this is my query:

```json
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"query_string": {
          "query": "*bop-qa-io-135*",
          "default_field": "errors.message", 
          "default_operator": "AND"}},
          {"range": {"updated_at": {"gte": "2023-07-03T00:00:00"}}},
          {"range": {"updated_at": {
            "lte": "2023-07-05T00:00:00"}}}]}}, "from": 0, "size": 300}
```

The type of `errors.message` is `text`. This query doesn't give me what I want, I know that the standard analyzer is working behind the scenes here to split my hyphenated query into separated terms etc.
My question is if there's a way to make this query work under the constraints detailed above?
What I've already tried:

- Adding `"analyzer": "keyword"` to the query

I think there was something about putting everything in double-quotes that should've worked but I don't know how to do it here - there's already double quotes as part of the JSON syntax.

My ES version:

```json
{
  "name": "GYWR05J",
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid": "vFO2BdrzR0OLfPeVO9Rr-g",
  "version": {
    "number": "6.2.2",
    "build_hash": "10b1edd",
    "build_date": "2018-02-16T19:01:30.685723Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think there was something about putting everything in double-quotes that should've worked but I don't know how to do it here

You can escape `-` with `\-` and put everything in quotes by escaping them with `\"`. So you will get something like this: `"query": "\"*bop\\-qa\\-io\\-135*\""` but it will not help you because `query_string` query doesn't work with wildcards. You can either choose wildcard or choose phrases there, but not both.

Unfortunately, if you cannot reindex, the solution is not going to be simple. First, you need to analyze your request to see which tokens are generated:

```
POST test/_analyze
{
  "field": "errors.message",
  "text": ["bop-qa-io-135"]
}
```

Then from the generated tokens you need to create a `span_near` query with `span_multi` with `wildcard` query for the first and the last terms and with `span_term` for all other terms. The terms should be in the format produced by the `_analyze` request. So, for `*bop-qa-io-135*` we will get

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "wildcard": {
                "errors.message": "*bop"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "span_term": {
            "errors.message": "qa"
          }
        },
        {
          "span_term": {
            "errors.message": "io"
          }
        },
        {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "wildcard": {
                "errors.message": "135*"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "in_order": true
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 300
}
```

If reindexing is an option, you can use an analyzer that is better suited for your type of text. There are numerous options. You can use whitespace analyzer for example, or use char filter to map `-` to some character that is not getting split by the analyzer for example `_`. One side effect of this approach is that because the character filter is applied for both indexing and searching searching for both `-` or `_` will return both `-` and `_`:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "nonsplit_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "nonsplit_char_filter"
            ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "nonsplit_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "- => _"
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer":"nonsplit_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
  
POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"text": "bazbop-qa-io-135678"}
{"index":{}}
{"text": "foobop_qa_io_135678"}
{"index":{}}
{"text": "foobop-qa-io-234567"}
{"index":{}}
{"text": "foobop qa io 135678"}


POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "text",
      "query": "*bop-qa-io-135*"
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "text",
      "query": "*bop_qa_io_135*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can it be that the same thing but with `"query": "*MyCustomError*"` does work? From what I understand it's just the hyphens that cause all the trouble. What do you mean by "choose phrase"?

Comment: `"query": "*MyCustomError*"` is a wildcard query. `"query": "\"*MyCustomError*\""` is a phrase query, which for the text field will send the text through analyzer, which will produce `MyCustomError` and then it will search for `MyCustomError` in the field errors.message.

Comment: The problem with hyphens is that they are treated like spaces by default analyzer. So searching for `*bop-qa-io-135*` is the same as searching for `*bop qa io 135*`.

Comment: I see. And why specifying the analyzer to use in this query does not take effect?

Comment: Analyzer is applied during indexing and during searching with full-text queries. During indexing the text is analyzed into terms and these terms are then indexed. When you apply the same analyzer to your full-text query, it produces the same terms, you search for these terms in the index and this is how you find records. Applying a different analyzer to just query will produce different terms that might not exists in the index. So, in your example you will try to search index for term `*bop-qa-io-135*` while in the index this record will be represented with terms `foobop`, `qa`, `io` and `135`

Comment: What are my options in the case of reindexing? From what I understand it's either changing the field's type (undesired) or changing/adding an analyzer to this field. What are the consequences of defining that this field won't be analyzed? I get that terms will be matched as they are, but what are the downsides for this? Also, I am not limited to the `query_string` query if there's another query that can give me better results.

Comment: The simplest option is to add an analyzer with char filter that will replace '-' with `_`. There are could be also better analyzer depending on what you store in this field. Regarding your second question, there is a good article describing pros and cons of choosing text vs keyword types for log message fields - https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field Spoiler: the most important consideration here will be the size of that field. Since it seems to be some sort of a message, you will most likely have to adjust `ignore_above`

Comment: Thank you very much, that article is very helpful. Can you add an example of using this simple "replace - with _" analyzer to the answer? If I understood correctly it's adding an analyzer in addition to the standard (default) analyzer? If so, which one take precedence? And, with this new analyzer - users will have to search for `bop_qa_io_135` instead?

Comment: I added an example. You will need to replace the standard analyzer with your own analyzer with a char_filter. Starting with version 5.x (I think) the char_filter is applied to both indexed document and wildcard terms in search queries, so you don't have to modify the query.

Comment: Is there a possibility to make the char_filter apply only for searching and not for indexing? I still want to keep my raw data with the original `-` and only in searching use the `_` trick.

Comment: I think you have a wrong assumption about what’s getting indexed. With the standard analyzer you are splitting words on `-` and throwing `-` away. After indexing there is no difference between `bop-qa-io-135` and `bop QA/IO 135. You can see it for yourself by running 

POST _analyze
{
  "text": ["bop QA/IO 135"]
}

and

POST _analyze
{
  "text": ["bop-qa-io-135"]
}

Both commands produce exactly the same tokens, which are then indexed. To keep raw data you need to index it using a different analyzer or no analyzer at all storing it in a keyword field, which has other issues.

Comment: ok, does the reindexing supposed to take time or is it instant? I have made the changes you suggested with the char_filter but still I am unable to find something like `bop-qa-io-140` which is actually part of a bigger fqdn e.g. `bop-qa-io-140.comp.it.com`. The query I am using is: ```POST /test/_search
{"query": {"bool": {"must": [{"query_string": {"query": "*bop-qa-io-140*","default_field": "errors.message"}}]}}}```

Comment: I just answered that the other day :) Check my last comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77114309/does-re-index-in-elasticsearch-has-zero-down-time/77114423#77114423

Comment: Thanks! so I tried to reindex with:```POST /_reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{"source": {"index": "test"},"dest": {"index": "test-temp"}}```
And I still can't find any results to my query with the new index. How can it be?

Comment: It's hard to tell. I just tested it on 6.2.2 and with some small adjustments it works as well as on 8.x - https://gist.github.com/imotov/742971eccf8a1d8c04e35a27ca6442e9 Check the example, compare it with your test-temp.

Comment: You delete and create the index but I have to reindex. When I view the settings of the new index (the result of my previous comment's command) I see no mention of the custom analyzer nor the char filter.

Comment: I have updated the gist above with reindexing, it makes absolutely no difference unless you are not telling me something important about your index, like you didn't store source for some fields, or there is some additional pre-processing or some other non-standard practices.

Comment: Since the relevant field is `errors.message` I changed the mapping part to:```"mappings": {"test": {"properties": {"errors": {"properties": {"message": {"type": "text","analyzer":"nonsplit_analyzer"}}}}}}``` (since the father field there is "test" and I don't need to use `_doc`).
And finally it worked!! Thank you so much. If I'll have more questions - is there a chat server of some kind that I can reach out to you there?

Comment: I check the questions here almost daily. If you need paid consultation I can give you my contact information.