# Does Re-index in Elasticsearch has zero-down time?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, reindex

Currently, I'm working with Elasticsearch, I'm interested in reindexing because it has no time down. I have a question if my index has very much data (1 million documents for example), when I call **POST _reindex**, all documents in old index are transferred immediately to new index? Or I have to wait until all documents is completed to query in new index?

Answer (score 1):

Reindex will take time since as the name suggests it re-indexes all the document from one index to another. No downtime means that your source index will be still available during the process. Two things to keep in mind during reindexing though:

1. Reindexing will be reading documents and indexing them, so it will have impact for both disk, I/O and CPU utilization. Make sure that your cluster has capacity to accommodate such load.
2. It takes time to reindex. So, if your source index will receive any updates during this process, these updates might not be reflected in the target index. So, the simplest solution would be to pause updating the source index and the restart updates already with the new index.

Comment: So how we know when the re-index is complete in new index? Currently I use curl to call POST _reindex

Comment: As I know, Elasticsearch will response code 200 immediately after a call to reindex

Comment: Yes reindex runs asynchronously by default. So instead of blocking until it is done it does a bit of checks and returns that task_id. You can either make it synchronous (you should run it using curl in this case since requests in kibana time out) or you can pool the task to see if it is done yet. Read the docs for more information https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api